# 'iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *' was not found in the accoun

Tags: ios, ionic3, visual-studio-app-center

I'm trying to upload to app center the ipa for iOS and I have trouble with the devices that I have included. It tells me that they are "unprovisioned". I've tried to make a registration of the devices which according to appcenter it's a 3 step process (I suppose in AppHockey it's the same), i.e.

- Register devices
- Update provisioning profile
- Re-sign app & upload new release

The first two succeed but I have an issue in the 3rd. It tells me Profile named 'iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *' was not found in the account.

I have tried in a MAC to export the p12 certificates, create a provision profile for my app, but with no success. I'm not sure what 'iOS Tem Provisioning Profile: *' means.

The project has been built from an ionic3 application. Not sure if it plays a role.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just in case somebody else has the same issue. I will mention all the steps I followed. It was related to the provisioning profile, which had to be used manually from xcode:

A. https://developer.apple.com

1. Identifiers->App IDs->create new App (or existing)
2. Devices->all->add new device (you need the uuid of the device)
3. Provisioning Profiles->Development-> new (iOS App Development)->choose app id from step 1->all certificates->all devices
4. Provisioning Profile->choose the one from step 3->download

B. XCode 10

1. open the app in xcode
2. Left side choose in project the root element
3. General Tab
4. Bundle identifier->the same as id in step A1
5. Signing->unclick Automatically managed signing
6. Signing (debug, Release)->Provisioning Profile->import profile from step A4
7. Product-> a. Clean build Folder, b. Destination->Generic iOS device, c. Build, d. Archive
   8.From the archive window-> a. Distribute App, b. Development->next, c. Manually manage signing, d.Distribution Certificate Default, e. MyApp.app->profile downloaded in step4, f. export (it has the ipa)